# Ng-Click NOT working (Angular Datatables)

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with my angular datatables . 
First, My code work very good, but after i add the code configure notSortable() for some colum , the ng-click of button is not working , and i can't fix it . Could you help me?

Here are my Code :
1> File index.html

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Button</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr dt-rows ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <td ng-bind="person.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="person.firstName"></td>
        <td ng-bind="person.lastName"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" ng-click="doClick()">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

2>File app.js

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('datatablesSampleApp', ['datatables']).
    controller('simpleCtrl', function($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        $scope.persons = [];
        $http.get('data.json').success(function(persons) {
            $scope.persons = persons;
        });
        $scope.doClick=function(){
            alert("Clicked button !")
        }
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers').withDisplayLength(40);
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID').notSortable(),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Button').withTitle('Button')
        ];

    });
```

})(angular);

Comment: can you try close the input field ?  <input type="button" ng-click="doClick()" />

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
<input type="button" ng-click="doClick()">
```

In stead of that try to use:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="doClick()">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to specify the controller in your index.html with ng-controller='simpleCtrl'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, below is the solution that worked for me

```
**1. Step 1 is same , repeating for the sake of completeness**
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Button</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr dt-rows ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <td ng-bind="person.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="person.firstName"></td>
        <td ng-bind="person.lastName"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" ng-click="doClick()">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

**Step2, In Controller, do the following**

(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('datatablesSampleApp', ['datatables']).
    controller('simpleCtrl', function($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

      $scope.persons = []
     $scope.init = function() {

      $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
          .withOption('aLengthMenu', [[-1], ['All']]) // Length of how many to show per pagination.
          .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
          .withBootstrap();
          $http.get("data.json").then( function(result){
              $scope.persons = result.data
           });
     }
     $scope.init()

    });
})(angular);
```